# tab bar presenting performance issue

Tags: iphone

i have a view controller with some custom buttons in it, AND AFTER CLICKING a button i am presenting  different view .and to one of the button click i am presenting a tab bar controller with navigation controller  .

and the code is as follows

```
TabBarView *tabbar=[[TabBarView alloc]init];
        UINavigationController *navNextController       = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabbar];
        [self presentModalViewController:navNextController animated:YES];
```

and in tab bar the code is as follows

```
UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
tabbarcontroller.delegate=self;


ShoppingListView *shop;
shop = [[ShoppingListView alloc] init];
shop.parentVC=self;
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:shop];
[localNavigationController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Lists"];
[localNavigationController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[IMBundle fullBundlePath:@"Images.bundle/Images/EnhancedMobileLists/list.png"]]];   
[localNavigationController viewWillAppear:YES];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
[localNavigationController release];
[shop release];

FavoritesViewController *fav;
fav = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] init];
fav.parentVC=self;
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fav];
[localNavigationController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Favorites" ];
[localNavigationController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[IMBundle fullBundlePath:@"Images.bundle/Images/EnhancedMobileLists/favorites.png"]]];  
[localNavigationController viewWillAppear:YES];
[localNavigationController viewWillDisappear:YES];
[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
[localNavigationController release];
[fav release];

ShareListViewController *share;
share = [[ShareListViewController alloc] init];
share.parentVC=self;
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:share];
[localNavigationController.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Share" ];
[localNavigationController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[IMBundle fullBundlePath:@"Images.bundle/Images/EnhancedMobileLists/share.png"]]];  
[localNavigationController viewWillAppear:YES];

[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
[localNavigationController release];
[share release];

tabbarcontroller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
[self.view addSubview:tabbarcontroller.view];
```

the main problem is while clicking the button to present the tab bar view it takes time to load ie for a moment it  appears as if  the view is hanged  and i am presenting a navigation view in another button and it is working fine with out any delay . please tell me whats wrong with my code and how to rectify the delay to present a tab bar while clicking a uibutton in iphone.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is written into the Appdelegate file and then this method is call on the button when tap on the button this method is call.

> -(void)ShowTabAbout{  [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];      self.imgV.frame=CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 55);
>     self.imgV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tBar5.png"];  [self.tabctr.view
>   addSubview:self.imgV];    self.tabctr.selectedIndex=4;    // [self
>   animationTabCode];    [window addSubview:tabctr.view];
>
> ```
>  }
> ```

Following code for the Animation for navigate the view controller.

> -(void)animationTabBarCode{
>
> ```
>  tr.type=kCATransitionPush;
>  tr.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
>
>
>  tr.delegate=self;
> ```
>
> [self.window.layer addAnimation:tr forKey:nil];  }

following code is implanted into the button which located view controller method file.

> -(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender{
>
> [appDelegate ShowTabAbout];
>
> ```
>  [appDelegate animationTabBarCode];
> ```
>
> }

Comment: For more detail about custom Tabbar following reference link to refer http://sugartin.info/2011/07/01/customizing-tab-bar/